PowerShell installing the Module SqlServerDSC
I am using a VM Server 2016 that does have access to the internet.
I am trying to install the Module SqlServerDSC
Whe I enter the following command line, Install-Module -Name SqlServerDsc
I get two warnings and 3 errors:
WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The
package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7468 char:21

...     $null = PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider -Name $script:N ...

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProv
ider], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider



PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria and provider name 'NuGet'. Try
'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable' to see if the provider exists on the system.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7474 char:21

...     $null = PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider -Name $script:Nu ...

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (NuGet:String) [Import-PackageProvider], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.ImportPackageProvider



WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider : Unable to find package provider 'NuGet'. It may not be imported yet. Try
'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7478 char:30

... tProvider = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -Name $script:NuGet ...

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:GetPackageProvider) [Get-PackageProvider], Ex
ception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnknownProviderFromActivatedList,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackageProvid
er



Install-Module : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that '2.8.5.201' or newer
version of NuGet provider is installed.
At line:1 char:1

Install-Module -Name SqlServerDsc

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Module], InvalidOperationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotInstallNuGetProvider,Install-Module




I have uninstalled and re-installed the Network Adapter 2 as a Bridge.
Opened CMD and pinged www.google.com got a positive reply
I evne tried from PowerShell to open a website
Start-Process "http://google.com", the webpage opened with no issues.
I do not understand how come I get these errors when I process a simple line of command...
any ideas or thoughts?

See https://sqlrambling.net/2019/09/30/installing-powershell-module-without-internet-access/
